# Where is the Debug -> Exceptions window?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, exception, debugging

I must be slow or something today, I cannot find this menu option. I attached a screenshot of my IDE's Debug menu:

[image: IDE]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right mouse click on the menu and select customize from the drop down.  Click Commands, then select the Debug Category.  On the right drag the Exception command to the toolbar or menu location you want it.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl + Alt +E. Use that all the time during debugging. Wish you could save the selected/excluded exceptions as a filter for later sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl + D, E

Answer (score 0):

Was it there before or not ? Look at Tools - Options - General - Debugging